# Firebase Function with where in clause

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I had this piece of code in Cloud Function which runs quite well when the array size is less than 10, as per documentation. But if the collection has more than 10 I am unable to get my code to run. Here are the 2 code snippets below, and the execution once I get my snapshot.

```
if (offline.length > 0) {
    console.log("[TAG =>", messageDocId, "] The array of offline users array length is", offline.length);
    return admin.firestore().collectionGroup('devices').where('uid', 'in', offline).get();
}
return null;
```

So I modified the above array to have chunks of 10 and then used a promise to fetch the data for all the chunks like this.

```
if (offline.length > 0) {
    console.log("[TAG =>", roomName, "->-",messageDocId,"] The array of offline users array length is =", offline.length);
    var i,j,temparray,chunk = 10;
    for (i=0,j=offline.length; i<j; i+=chunk) {
        temparray = offline.slice(i,i+chunk);
        console.log("[TAG =>", roomName, "->-",messageDocId,"] Priniting Chunks", temparray);
        offlinePromises.push(admin.firestore().collectionGroup('devices').where('uid', '==', offline[i]).get());
    }
    console.log("[TAG =>", roomName, "->-",messageDocId,"] starting promise execution");
        return Promise.all(offlinePromises);
    }
```

Also the codebase below either of the two code snippets above is below.

```
.then(snapshot => {
            if(snapshot === null){
                console.log("[TAG =>", roomName, "->-",messageDocId,"] The snapshot is null");  
            }
            if (offline === null || offline.length === 0 || snapshot === null) {
                console.log("[TAG =>", roomName, "->-",messageDocId,"] The array of offline users is null");
                return null;
            }
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                try {
                    token = doc.data().rt;
                    outputTokenList.push(token);
                } catch (tokenfetcherror) {
                    console.log("[TAG =>", roomName, "->-",messageDocId,"] unable to fetch tokens for =>", doc.id);
                }
            });
            return outputTokenList;

        }).then(response => { // prepare the payload and a batch of upto 500 and send push messages.
            if(response === null){
                return null;
            }
            console.log("[TAG =>", roomName, "->-",messageDocId,"] Successfully prepared token list ", response);

            var tokenChunks = [];

            while (response.length) {
                tokenChunks.push(response.splice(0, 400));
            }

            for (batchTokens of tokenChunks) {
                console.log("[TAG =>", roomName, "->-",messageDocId,"] Chunked token list ", batchTokens);
                let promise = admin.messaging().sendToDevice(batchTokens, payload, options);
                promises.push(promise);
            }
            return Promise.all(promises);
        })
        .then(batchResponse => { // you can handle removal candidates using this.
            if(batchResponse === null){
                console.log("[TAG =>", roomName, "->-",messageDocId,"] No Messages to send.");
                return false;
            }
            console.log("[TAG =>", roomName, "->-",messageDocId,"] Messages Sent, handle removals later");
            console.log("[TAG =>", roomName, "->-",messageDocId,"] batchResponse =>", batchResponse);
            return true;
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log("[TAG =>", roomName, "->-",messageDocId,"] Error sending message ", error);
            return false;
        })
});
```

Is there a problem with the way I have written the Promise. Please assist. TIA

Comment: While you may run this code in Cloud Functions, you didn't share any code that is related to Cloud Functions specifically, nor any messages that indicate that it is specific to Cloud Functions. I retagged `google-cloud-firestore`, which clearly is being used and relevant to the question. If the question is only reproducible on Cloud Functions, please ensure that details around that are present in your question.

Comment: We have no way to know what `offline` is, nor how its value affects the behavior that you're asking about. Please edit your question to include the value of `offline`, preferably hard-coded, so that we can be sure we're looking at the same values you are.

Comment: offline is an array of user ids prepared from a document snapshot. @FrankvanPuffelen . Will edit the question as well to include the entire cloud function.

Comment: Honestly: I'd much rather see that you reduce the code, not expand it. The smaller the reproduction, the more likely someone is to be able to help. Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).